# looping an array inside the function in jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi how can we loop an array inside the jquery function.In the downloadCSV function if you observe means in items i am taking the 0th array.So i am hard coding that array now.So now there are n number of arrays.so how can i loop it inside the function?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href='#' onclick='downloadCSV({ filename: "youtubeData.csv" });'>Download CSV</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {});

        function convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(args) {
            var result, ctr, keys, columnDelimiter, lineDelimiter, data;
            data = args.data || null;
            if (data == null || !data.length) {
                return null;
            }
            columnDelimiter = args.columnDelimiter || ',';
            lineDelimiter = args.lineDelimiter || '\n';
            keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
            result = '';
            result += keys.join(columnDelimiter);
            result += lineDelimiter;
            data.forEach(function(item) {
                ctr = 0;
                keys.forEach(function(key) {
                    if (ctr > 0) result += columnDelimiter;
                    result += item[key];
                    ctr++;
                    console.log("columnDelimiter " + result);
                });
                result += lineDelimiter;
            });
            return result;

        }

        function downloadCSV(args) {
            var youtubeData = [];
            var data, filename, link;
            $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key=""&textFormat=plainText&part=snippet,replies&videoId=eDHFc24mp38&maxResults=60', function(data) {
                youtubeData.push({
                    "comments": data.item[0].snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.authorDisplayName,


                });
                console.log(data.item[0].snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.authorDisplayName);
                var csv = convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV({
                    data: youtubeData
                });
                if (csv == null) return;

                filename = args.filename || 'export.csv';

                if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
                    csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
                }
                data = encodeURI(csv);

                link = document.createElement('a');
                link.setAttribute('href', data);
                link.setAttribute('download', filename);
                link.click();
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the for loop to iterate the data.item as explained below:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.item.length; i++) {
    youtubeData.push({
        "comments": data.item[i].snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.authorDisplayName,
    });
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: i am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: function downloadCSV(args) {
            var items = [];
            var youtubeData = [];
            var data, filename, link;
            $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?key=AIzaSyBQBYrZCovwDLF9p1m8JrABiYmJ6g928y0&textFormat=plainText&part=snippet,replies&videoId=eDHFc24mp38&maxResults=60', function(data) {
                for(var i = 0; i < data.item.length; i++) {
                youtubeData.push({
                    "comments": data.items[i].snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.authorDisplayName
                });
                }

Comment: If this answer is helpful , you can upvote it ;) @ABHISHEKL